# FAILED: RuntimeException Hive internal error: conversion of string to void not supported yet

Tags: hadoop, azure-hdinsight

NULL selection as column in a union/sub-queries failed with internal error

Failing HIVE query:

```
select clientid from hivesampletable limit 1 union all select null as clientid;
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive internal error: conversion of string to void not supported yet.
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(ObjectInspectorConverters.java:132)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(ObjectInspectorConverters.java:152)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.typeCast(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:178)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.evaluateColumn(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:525)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.foldExprFull(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:328)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.foldExpr(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:222)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.foldExprFull(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:296)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.foldExpr(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:222)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory.access$000(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:93)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagateProcFactory$ConstantPropagateSelectProc.process(ConstantPropagateProcFactory.java:796)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultRuleDispatcher.dispatch(DefaultRuleDispatcher.java:90)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatchAndReturn(DefaultGraphWalker.java:94)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.dispatch(DefaultGraphWalker.java:78)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagate$ConstantPropagateWalker.walk(ConstantPropagate.java:155)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lib.DefaultGraphWalker.startWalking(DefaultGraphWalker.java:109)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.ConstantPropagate.transform(ConstantPropagate.java:125)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:178)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:10146)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:221)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:417)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1069)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1131)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1006)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:996)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:345)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:443)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:459)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:739)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
                at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about the question rather than just the stack trace to help any other members of the community who come across this post in future

Comment: While self-answers are encouraged here, you must first **write a question** that has to meet the same quality standards as any other question here; you can then post an **answer** to that question (again, meeting the same quality standards as any other answer). A title and a stack trace dump does not meet the quality standards for a question, particularly when the title is nothing but a mirror of the first line in the stack trace. You need to describe the problem, include the code that is causing the problem, and ask a question. You can then post a solution, explaining why the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

CAST NULL explicitly to the required type to work around it.

Ex:  select cast(null as string)